# What is answering at port 80 when httpd is down?

Tags: macos, network, webserver

Since OS X Lion, web sharing isn't available from the System preferences.

So I shut it down using `sudo apachectl stop`. Doing this, `http://localhost/~Username` doesn't answer any more and all `httpd` are down (a least `ps -e | grep httpd` return none of them).

But using my browser `http://localhost` still returns a "It works!". Who then is answering at port 80 ?

Comment: yeah ... I don't how I could oversee that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing. Your browser is likely returning a cached response. Try Shift+Reload or clear your cache and reload. Then, you should see no response.